# How to download the trained models from Azure machine studio?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created two models in azure ml studio and i want to download those models.

Is it possible to download train and score models from azure ml studio?

Comment: you mean download to the local machine & run locally? It's not possible to download experiments to the local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models can be trained, scored, saved, and run in AzureML studio, but can't downloaded to your local machine. There's no way to do anything with a model outside of AzureML.

Comment: This is so wrong for the 2020 version of azure-sdk. You CAN download model or train locally. AzureML Studio and its workspace can act as an experiment wrapper.

Comment: That's great news! My answer was written 3 years ago.

Comment: just an update, however, AWS is still out of the sight for this feature, which is quite weird.

Comment: @BrianNg would you please explain more, how we can download the model trained in AzureML to our local machine?

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible. First, transform your experiment as a retraining web-service, then download (right-click on the module) the output of the web-service module that is connected to the "train model" module.
[image: Sample 5: Train, Test, Evaluate for Binary Classification: Adult Dataset]

Comment: As far as I know there is no option to download when you right-click the web-service module. It has no output.

Comment: You can, trust me I work in this team ;).
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2017/06/19/loading-a-trained-model-dynamically-in-an-azure-ml-web-service/

Comment: It should still be working... If you are facing an issue, please reach out to the team (I've left).

Comment: This requires web access and an API key. While still useful, it's not the same as downloading the model itself.

(Some of the example code:         
    print("The results for " + outputName + " are available at the following Azure Storage location:"))

Comment: Hi @Ahmet I have tried what you mentioned but I am not able to download the model onto a local computer. Would it be possible for you to share more details on this one.

Comment: @Ahmet I have written a more detailed question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775579/download-a-trained-ml-model-from-azure-ml-studio-to-deploy-on-a-standalone-compu

Answer (score 0):

From this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-pytorch

"You can also download a local copy of the model by using the Run
object. In the training script pytorch_train.py, a PyTorch save object
persists the model to a local folder (local to the compute target). You
can use the Run object to download a copy."

```
# Create a model folder in the current directory
os.makedirs('./model', exist_ok=True)

# Download the model from run history
run.download_file(name='outputs/model.pt',
output_file_path='./model/model.pt')
```

This is available for different frameworks: pytorch, keras etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
az ml model download --model-id
                     --target-dir
                     [--overwrite]
                     [--path]
                     [--resource-group]
                     [--subscription-id]
                     [--workspace-name]
                     [-v]
```

you gotta install azure-cli though