# How to use the trained model developed in AZURE ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I trained a model in AZURE ML. Now i want to use that model in my ios app to predict the output .

How to download the model from AZURE and use it my swift code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the model could run in **Azure Machine Learning Studio**.It seems that you are unable to download it, the model could do nothing outside of Azure ML.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236871/how-to-download-the-trained-models-from-azure-machine-studio) is a similar post for you to refer, I have also tried @Ahmet's 
method, but result is like @mrjrdnthms says.