# Embedded Azure MLmodel

Tags: android, azure, sdk, azure-machine-learning-service

Suppose I have a trained model in [Azure ML](https://studio.azureml.net) and I deployed it as a Web Service. Is it possible to export the model, embed it in an Android app and use it *locally*, without making any requests to Azure Web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236871/how-to-download-the-trained-models-from-azure-machine-studio) you won't be able to save the model locally if you do everything within Azure ML Studio.

If you create the model using Python or R and execute it within Azure ML Studio, then you can save it from the library that you use.